# How to use efficiently Jazzy ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, jazzylistview

In my app I want swiping my screen horizontally.I use view pager And Fragment for that.But I want to use Jazzy ViewPager. Which is More Stylist And sexy.I used this link
 https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager.But i want to inflate my layout xml here .How I will do it.plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer itself is given there, just import the library JazzyViewpager in your project by right clicking your project and add it as a reference library and then in your code  write the following code:

In your PagerAdapter write:

```
private JazzyViewPager mJazzy;
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
mJazzy.setObjectForPosition(obj, position);
return obj;
}
```

and select your animation by calling:

```
 private JazzyViewPager mJazzy;
 mJazzy.setTransitionEffect(TransitionEffect.*);
```

The JazzyViewPager's animations are encapsulated 
in TransitionEffect.

```
public enum TransitionEffect {
    Standard,
    Tablet,
    CubeIn,
    CubeOut,
    Flip,
    Stack,
    ZoomIn,
    ZoomOut,
    RotateUp,
    RotateDown,
    Accordion
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to do both direction horizontal and vertical at a time